# how to attach ajax requests into symonfy2 controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony-2.8

My Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){   
    var ids = ['filter_1','filter_2','filter_3','filter_4'];    
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
      if(document.getElementById(ids[i]).checked === true){
      var data = {request : $('#'+ ids[i]).val()};        
        } 
    }    
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: Routing.generate('listingpage'),
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: data,        
        success: function(result,status,xhr){
           var inst_arr = JSON.parse(result);              
           console.log(inst_arr);
           }  
       });
      });
      });
```

Here i have multiple check boxes with ids 'filter_1','filter_2','filter_3','filter_4' while sending ajax request it returns request individually. How can i attach multiple requests (like if i select two check boxes i want to show two requests into at a time) into single request.

My Controller Code:

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){  
        $data = $request->request->get('request');
      //  $this->container->get('logger')->addInfo('somesh'.$data);           
        $repository = $em->getRepository('EdufactionBundle:Institute');    
        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('i');  
        $query = $queryBuilder
                     ->innerJoin('i.instsummary', 's')    
                     ->innerJoin('i.address', 'a') 
                     ->innerJoin('i.insturl', 'u') 
                     ->select('s.instaffiliation')
                     ->setParameter('instaffiliation', $data)
                     ->getQuery()->getResult();  
       return $json = new Response(json_encode($query));
       }
```

Here controller data if i select first checkbox it returns 1 and if i select checkbox 2 it returns 2. how can i post two checkbox data into single request and how can i bind multiple requests into single request.
Please help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

One soulution for you is [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to run multi ajax request one after another. working like this :

```
$.when( $.ajax( "Your first ajax request" ), $.ajax( "Your second ajax request" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
   // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the your two ajax requests, respectively.
   // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]

  //HERE Do something after all requests was done
  console.log("Do Something...");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Emad Dehnavi, I want to send as a requests dynamic way to controller

Comment: how can i bind multiple requests to using var data = {request : $('#'+ ids[i]).val()};

Comment: how to pass controller $data as array like array(1,2,3) values[->setParameter('instaffiliation', $data)]